# Tooltip Mouseover Event Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want some text to change when someone mouses over a button. I have used an event handler, but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```js
var MyButton = document.getElementById("MyButton");

MyButton.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
tooltip(1);
});

  function tooltip(thing) {
if (thing = 1) {
document.getElemenyById("tooltipText").innerHTML = "Test!!!";
 }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="MyButton">
  Hover Over Me!
</button>
```

Comment: `if (thing === 1)` or `if (thing == 1)` when comparing not `if (thing = 1)`.

Comment: Did this but it still will not change.

Comment: Get into the habit of checking the console before asking for help... `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElemenyById is not a function`

Comment: missing a `t` in `getElementById`

Comment: Thanks Archer, I will use this more often. Thanks to Derlin as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `document.getElemenyById`, should be `document.getElementById`:

```js
var MyButton = document.getElementById("MyButton");

MyButton.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  tooltip(1);
});

function tooltip(thing) {
  if (thing === 1) { // also use === for comparison not =
    document.getElementById("tooltipText").innerHTML = "Test!!!";
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="MyButton">
  Hover Over Me!
</button>
<span id="tooltipText">
</span>
```